# QGIS trace dotted path from xyz tiles layer

Tags: qgis, digitization

I am using QGIS 3.28.3-Firenze
and I have added in my project a XYZ tiles layer from a custom url of the form https://xxxxxxxxx//{x}/{-y}.png

This layer has specific dotted "paths" (black and white) as the image below:

[image]

Is there a way to auto trace these paths without manually drawing polygons and raster tracer for example?